# Precise definition of exponential convergence of a summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

What is the precise definition of a summation converging exponentially? In equation (2.46) of this [paper](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/731/art%253A10.1023%252FA%253A1004377501747.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1023%2FA%3A1004377501747&token2=exp=1480585154~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F731%2Fart%25253A10.1023%25252FA%25253A1004377501747.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1023%252FA%253A1004377501747*~hmac=6402fb66c401a83178b8cbec020a57df391fc7daa835d7832fc84e265d8032c0) it says the summation converges exponentially but the convergence is not dependant on some exponential term such as $e^{-ax}$ so I'm not sure what exponential convergence is supposed to signify.

The wikipedia article on [rates of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence) also doesn't give a definitive answer and if I search google for "exponential convergence definition" I get lots of results on exponential convergence but none actually give a precise definition of it which is surprising. So what exactly is it?

Comment: Could you write equation $(2.46)$ of the paper since it not freely accessible ?

Comment: Exponential convergence is a broad statement.  Be specific.